# How to convert CJK Extention B in QLineEdit of Python3-PyQt4 to utf-8 to Processing it with regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pyqt4, cjk, python-unicode

I have a code like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import re
.....
str = self.lineEdit.text() # lineEdit is a object in QtGui.QLineEdit class

# This line thanks to Fedor Gogolev et al from 
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214801/print-a-string-as-hex-bytes

print('\\u'+"\\u".join("{:x}".format(ord(c)) for c in str))
# u+20000-u+2a6d6 is CJK Ext B
cjk = re.compile("^[一-鿌㐀-䶵\U00020000-\U0002A6D6]+$",re.UNICODE) 

if cjk.match(str):
    print("OK")
else:
    print("error")
```

when I inputted "敏感詞" (0x654F,0x611F, 0x8A5E in utf16 respectively), the result was:

```
\u654f\u611f\u8a5e
OK
```

but when I input "詞" (0x8A5E, 0xD840 0xDC37, 0xD840 0xDC81,  0xD840 0xDC4D in utf-16) in which there were 3 characters from CJK Extention B Area. The result which is not expected is:

```
\u8a5e\ud840\udc37\ud840\udc81\ud840\udc4d
error
```

how can I processed these CJK characters with converting to utf-8 to be processed suitabliy with re of Python3?

**P.S.**

1. the value from sys.maxunicode is 1114111, it might be UCS-4. Hence, I think that the question seems not to be the same as 
   [python regex fails to match a specific Unicode > 2 hex values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966386/python-regex-fails-to-match-a-specific-unicode-2-hex-values)
2. another code:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   #-*-coding:utf-8-*-
   import re
   CJKBlock = re.compile("^[一-鿌㐀-䶵\U00020000-\U0002A6D6]+$") #CJK ext B
   print(CJKBlock.search('詞'))
   ```

returns `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='詞'>` #expected result.

3. even I added `self.lineEdit.setText("詞")` inside `__init__` function of the window class and executed it, the word in LineEdit shows appropriately, but when I pressed enter, the result was still "error"
4. version:

   - Python3.4.3
   - Qt version: 4.8.6
   - PyQt version: 4.10.4.

Comment: Why are you using a narrow-build of python-3.4? Since [PEP-0393](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/), there is no longer any advantage in doing that. Your code fails because the non-BMP characters have to be represented as surrogate pairs. If you switch to a wide-build of python-3.4, this problem will go away.

Comment: Re. @ekhumoro the returned value of  sys.maxunicode is 1114111, it might be in UCS-4.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*-encoding:utf-8-*-
import re; CJKBlock = re.compile("^[一-鿌㐀-䶵\U00020000-\U0002A6D6]+$"); #CJK ext B
    print(CJKBlock.search('詞')); returns <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='詞'> #expected result. but the string from QLineEdit fails to do that. Maybe It's the problem from Python3-PyQt4?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on a wide-build: it prints `\u8a5e\u20037\u20081\u2004d` as expected (i.e. no surrogate pairs). What **specific** version of pyqt4 are you using, and where did you get it from? How are you entering the text into the line-edit? Does it make any difference if enter it in code, using `setText()`?

Comment: [1]Qt version: 4.8.6, PyQt version: 4.10.4. [2]I get it from Linux Mint  Linux Mint 17.3 64-bit repo. [3] Key in the text in lineEdit, and `self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(the_function)`[4]even I added self.lineEdit.setText("詞") in __init__ function of the window and 
executed it, the word in LineEdit shows appropriately, but when I pressed enter, the result was still "error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few PyQt4 bugs following the implemetation of PEP-393 that can affect conversions between `QString` and python strings. If you use sip to switch to the v1 API, you should probably be able to confirm that the `QString` returned by the line-edit *does not* contain surrogate pairs. But if you then convert it to a python string, the surrogates should appear.

Here is how to test this in an interactive session:

```
>>> import sip
>>> sip.setapi('QString', 1)
>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui
>>> app = QtGui.QApplication([])
>>> w = QtGui.QLineEdit()
>>> w.setText('詞')
>>> qstr = w.text()
>>> qstr
PyQt4.QtCore.QString('詞')
>>> pystr = str(qstr)
>>> print('\\u' + '\\u'.join('{:x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in pystr))
\u8a5e\u20037\u20081\u2004d
```

Of course, this last line does not show surrogates for me, because I cannot do the test with PyQt-4.10.4. I have tested with PyQt-4.11.1 and PyQt-4.11.4, though, and I did not get see any problems. So you should try to upgrade to one of those.

Comment: As I update to python3-pyqt4 4.11.4 and python3-sip 4.16.9, the question has been solved. Thank you a lot.